# LDAP credentials error

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to access the LDAP server to get the user details, for which I have a following code but  it throws the below error of invalid credentials. Although the credentials are absolutely correct, I have verified by applying other user's credentials too, kindly guide me if I am missing something to connect to LDAP server?

> ORA-31202: DBMS_LDAP: LDAP client/server error: Invalid credentials. 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1

here is my code to access the LDAP server:

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE Refresh_ActiveDirectory
   IS
   l_ldap_host   VARCHAR2(256) := '10.133.10.22';
   l_ldap_port   VARCHAR2(256) := '389'; --Default
   l_ldap_user   VARCHAR2(256) := 'abl.com.pk\username';
   l_ldap_passwd VARCHAR2(256) := 'password';
   l_ldap_base   VARCHAR2(256) := 'OU=Central-I,dc=abl,dc=com, dc=pk';
   display_name      VARCHAR2(255);
   initials         VARCHAR2(255);
   samaccountname     VARCHAR2(255);
   email        VARCHAR2(255);
   department    VARCHAR2(255);
   grade         VARCHAR2(255);

   l_retval PLS_INTEGER;
   l_session DBMS_LDAP.session;
   l_attrs DBMS_LDAP.string_collection;
   l_message DBMS_LDAP.MESSAGE;
   l_entry DBMS_LDAP.MESSAGE;
   l_attr_name VARCHAR2(256);
   l_ber_element DBMS_LDAP.ber_element;
   l_vals DBMS_LDAP.string_collection;

  BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ACTIVEDIRECTORY_12_MAR_17';
 -- Choose to raise exceptions.
   DBMS_LDAP.USE_EXCEPTION := TRUE;
  -- Connect to the LDAP server.
   l_session := DBMS_LDAP.init(hostname => l_ldap_host, portnum =>    l_ldap_port);
   l_retval  := DBMS_LDAP.simple_bind_s(ld => l_session, dn => l_ldap_user, passwd => l_ldap_passwd);
  -- Get all attributes
  --l_attrs(1)                                                   :=      'displayName';
 -- l_attrs(2)                                                   :=     'initials';
  --l_attrs(3)                                                   := 'mailNickName';

    l_attrs(1)                                                   :=  'displayName';
    l_attrs(2)                                                   := 'initials';
    l_attrs(3)                                                   := 'samaccountname';
    l_attrs(3)                                                   := ' e-mail';
    l_attrs(3)                                                   := 'department';
     l_attrs(3)                                                   := 'department';
                 l_retval                                                         :=        DBMS_LDAP.search_s(ld => l_session, base => l_ldap_base, scope =>      DBMS_LDAP.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filter => '(&(&(objectclass=user) (!(physicaldeliveryofficename=no phone)))(!(useraccountcontrol=514)))', attrs => l_attrs, attronly => 0, res => l_message);
   IF DBMS_LDAP.count_entries(ld => l_session, msg => l_message) > 0 THEN
-- Get all the entries returned by our search.
l_entry := DBMS_LDAP.first_entry(ld => l_session, msg => l_message);
<< entry_loop >>
WHILE l_entry IS NOT NULL
LOOP
  -- Get all the attributes for this entry.
  l_attr_name := DBMS_LDAP.first_attribute(ld => l_session, ldapentry => l_entry, ber_elem => l_ber_element);
  --Clear variables
  /*dispname   := NULL;
  initials      := NULL;
  mailnickname  := NULL;*/
  display_name   := NULL;
  initials      := NULL;
  samaccountname  := NULL;
  email  := NULL;
  department  := NULL;
  grade  := NULL;

  WHILE l_attr_name IS NOT NULL
  LOOP
    -- Get all the values for this attribute.
    l_vals := DBMS_LDAP.get_values (ld => l_session, ldapentry => l_entry, attr => l_attr_name);

    FOR i IN l_vals.FIRST .. l_vals.LAST
    LOOP
      IF l_attr_name    = 'displayName' THEN
        display_name       := SUBSTR(l_vals(i),1,200);
      ELSIF l_attr_name = 'initials' THEN
        initials     := SUBSTR(l_vals(i),1,200);
      ELSIF l_attr_name = 'samaccountname' THEN
        samaccountname := SUBSTR(l_vals(i),1,200);
      ELSIF l_attr_name = 'e-mail' THEN
        email := SUBSTR(l_vals(i),1,200);
      ELSIF l_attr_name = 'department' THEN
        department := SUBSTR(l_vals(i),1,200);
      ELSIF l_attr_name = 'department' THEN
        grade := SUBSTR(l_vals(i),1,200);
      END IF ;
    END LOOP values_loop;
    l_attr_name := DBMS_LDAP.next_attribute(ld => l_session, ldapentry => l_entry, ber_elem => l_ber_element);
  END LOOP attibutes_loop;
  INSERT
  INTO ACTIVEDIRECTORY_12_MAR_17
    (
      STAFF_ID,
      FULL_NAME,
      USER_ID,
      EMAIL_ID,
      DEPARTMENT,
      GRADE


    )
    VALUES
    (
      initials,
      display_name,
      samaccountname,
      email,
      department,
      grade


    );
  l_entry := DBMS_LDAP.next_entry(ld => l_session, msg => l_entry);
END LOOP entry_loop;
  END IF;
  -- Disconnect from the LDAP server.
  l_retval := DBMS_LDAP.unbind_s(ld => l_session);
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      NULL;
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ROLLBACK;
      ERROR_LOGGER ('Refresh_ActiveDirectory', 'Refresh_ActiveDirectory', '', SQLCODE, substr(SQLERRM, 1, 500));
    --Delete non-person users

 END;
```

Comment: Please show us your code which throws the error. Declaring variables does not raise such error.

Comment: Please see the edited code

Answer (score 1):

I think the LDAP user must by the full DN, try

```
l_ldap_user VARCHAR2(256) := 'CN=username,OU=Central-I,dc=abl,dc=com,dc=pk
```

Comment: still the same issue